# Autocomplete Input with Python Selenium Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, autocomplete, geckodriver

I'm trying to fill an autocomplete input on this website google.com/flights but it seems something is not working as expected. When I check the output the input is clicked but the word "NYC" is never filled on the input. Test was done using Firefox with Geckodriver, last stable versions.

Here is the code:

```
inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.e5F5td.BGeFcf div.dvO2xc.k0gFV input')
inputElement.send_keys('NYC')
```

Here is a screenshot of what the browser sees after executing the code.
https://snipboard.io/i1YVNC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting the `NYC` to `inputElement` suggested inputs are appearing.
You can select one of them.
For example to select LGA airport you can click this element:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-code='LGA']").click()
```

**upd**
After clarifying the problem finally solved with sending the text with Actions instead of Selenium driver.

Comment: That's a great comment, I was actually just gonna press enter to select the first one but your approach is more solid. Regardless of that, my problem is that I'm not even seeing the suggestion box appears because the word "NYC" is not filled on the input to begin with.

Comment: Nothing, that's the weird part. Element is loaded and clickable, no exception or error at all is shown. It's just like the send_keys command gets ignored. Here is a screenshot of the browser and code is executed https://snipboard.io/i1YVNC.jpg

Comment: Well, need to debug this but I can't.. Can you put a big pause, like 10 seconds sleep, then click on that element, then short sleep and only after that send keys to the element?

Comment: The big pause is already there, and the click before send keys tried it too. I even tried different ways of clicking on selenium native, using js, etc. Seems the click works fine but the problem persists when sending the keys. I suspect it has to do with how the autocomplete works, but no idea how to fix it.